# Going through a list individually

Tags: python, arrays, list, iteration

I have very limited coding background except for some Ruby, so if there's a better way of doing this, please let me know!

Essentially I have a .txt file full of words. I want to import the .txt file and turn it into a list. Then, I want to take the first item in the list, assign it to a variable, and use that variable in an external request that sends off to get the definition of the word. The definition is returned, and tucked into a different .txt file. Once that's done, I want the code to grab the next item in the list and do it all again until the list is exhausted.

Below is my code in progress to give an idea of where I'm at. I'm still trying to figure out how to iterate through the list correctly, and I'm having a hard time interpreting the documentation.

Sorry in advance if this was already asked! I searched, but couldn't find anything that specifically answered my issue.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
import urllib2, urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

lines = []

with open('words.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for each in lines


wordlist = open('test.txt', 'a')

word = ##figure out how to get items from list and assign them here

url = 'http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/Default.aspx?action=define&dict=wn&query=%s' % word

# print url and make sure it's correct

html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
# print html (deprecated)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
visible_text = soup.find('pre')(text=True)[0]

print(visible_text, file=wordlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep everything in a loop. Like that:

```
with open('test.txt', 'a') as wordlist:
    for word in lines:
        url = 'http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/Default.aspx?action=define&dict=wn&query=%s' % word
        print url
        # print url and make sure it's correct
        html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        visible_text = soup.find('pre')(text=True)[0]
        wordlist.write("{0}\n".format(visible_text))
```

Secondly, some suggestions:

1. `f.readlines()` won't discard the trailing `\n`. So, I would use `f.read().splitlines()`

   ```
   lines = f.read().splitlines()
   ```
2. You don't to initialize the `lines` list with `[ ]`, as you are forming the list at one shot and assigning it to `lines`. You need to initialize the list, only when you consider using `append()` to the list.  So, the below line isn't needed.

   ```
   lines = []
   ```
3. You can handle `KeyError` by the following:

   ```
   try:
       value = soup.find('pre', text=True)[0]
       return value
   except KeyError:
       return None
   ```

Comment: So I've switched it up a bit, but I'm still getting errors. The updated code is here http://pastebin.com/VFY8VLat

Comment: That's because, may be for some data `return self.attrs[key]`  causes error that's because `key` doesn't exist for that particular data. You may be handle that with a `try/catch` block. See the updated answer for code example.

Answer (score 0):

I also show how you can use the Python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library for retrieving the raw html page. This allows us to easily check the status code for whether the retrieval was successful. You can replace the relevant lines to urllib with this if you like.

You can install `requests` in the command line using pip: `pip install requests`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import sys
import re
import requests
import urllib2, urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html_with_urllib(word):
    url = "http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/Default.aspx?action=define&dict=wn&query={word}".format(word=word)
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    return html


def get_html(word):
    url = "http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/Default.aspx?action=define&dict=wn&query={word}".format(word=word)
    response = requests.get(url)

    # Something bad happened
    if response.status_code != 200:
        return ""

    # Did not get back html
    if not response.headers["Content-Type"].startswith("text/html"):
        return ""

    html = response.content
    return html


def format_definitions(raw_definitions_text):
    # Get individual lines in definitions text
    parts = raw_definitions_text.split('\n')

    # Convert to str
    # Remove extra spaces on the left.
    # Add one space at the end for later joining with next line
    parts = map(lambda x: str(x).lstrip() + ' ', parts)

    result = []
    current = ""
    for p in parts:
        if re.search("\w*[0-9]+:", p):
            # Start of new line. Contains some char followed by <number>:

            # Save previous lines
            result.append(current.replace('\n', ' '))

            # Set start of current line
            current = p
        else:
            # Continue line
            current += p

    result.append(current)
    return '\n'.join(result)


def get_definitions(word):
    # Uncomment this to use requests
    # html = get_html(word)
    # Could not get definition
    # if not html:
        # return None

    html = get_html_with_urllib(word)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    # Get block containing definition
    definitions = soup.find("pre").get_text()

    definitions = format_definitions(definitions)
    return definitions


def batch_query(input_filepath):
    with open(input_filepath) as infile:
        for word in infile:
            word = word.strip()  # Remove spaces from both ends
            definitions = get_definitions(word)
            if not definitions:
                print("Could not retrieve definitions for {word}".format(word=word))

            print("Definition for {word} is: ".format(word=word))
            print(definitions)


def main():
    input_filepath = sys.argv[1]  # Alternatively, change this to file containing words
    batch_query(input_filepath)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
Definition for cat is: 
cat 
n 1: feline mammal usually having thick soft fur and being unable to roar; domestic cats; wildcats [syn: true cat] 
2: an informal term for a youth or man; "a nice guy"; "the guy's only doing it for some doll" [syn: guy, hombre, bozo] 
3: a spiteful woman gossip; "what a cat she is!" 
4: the leaves of the shrub Catha edulis which are chewed like tobacco or used to make tea; has the effect of a euphoric stimulant; "in Yemen kat is used daily by 85% of adults" [syn: kat, khat, qat, quat, Arabian tea, African tea] 
5: a whip with nine knotted cords; "British sailors feared the cat" [syn: cat-o'-nine-tails] 
6: a large vehicle that is driven by caterpillar tracks; frequently used for moving earth in construction and farm work [syn: Caterpillar] 
7: any of several large cats typically able to roar and living in the wild [syn: big cat] 
8: a method of examining body organs by scanning them with X rays and using a computer to construct a series of cross-sectional scans along a single axis [syn: computerized tomography, computed tomography, CT, computerized axial tomography, computed axial tomography] 
v 1: beat with a cat-o'-nine-tails 
2: eject the contents of the stomach through the mouth; "After drinking too much, the students vomited"; "He purged continuously"; "The patient regurgitated the food we gave him last night" [syn: vomit, vomit up, purge, cast, sick, be sick, disgorge, regorge, retch, puke, barf, spew, spue, chuck, upchuck, honk, regurgitate, throw up] [ant: keep down] [also: catting, catted]  
Definition for dog is: 
dog 
n 1: a member of the genus Canis (probably descended from the common wolf) that has been domesticated by man since prehistoric times; occurs in many breeds; "the dog barked all night" [syn: domestic dog, Canis familiaris] 
2: a dull unattractive unpleasant girl or woman; "she got a reputation as a frump"; "she's a real dog" [syn: frump] 
3: informal term for a man; "you lucky dog" 
4: someone who is morally reprehensible; "you dirty dog" [syn: cad, bounder, blackguard, hound, heel] 
5: a smooth-textured sausage of minced beef or pork usually smoked; often served on a bread roll [syn: frank, frankfurter, hotdog, hot dog, wiener, wienerwurst, weenie] 
6: a hinged catch that fits into a notch of a ratchet to move a wheel forward or prevent it from moving backward [syn: pawl, detent, click] 
7: metal supports for logs in a fireplace; "the andirons were too hot to touch" [syn: andiron, firedog, dog-iron] v : go after with the intent to catch; "The policeman chased the mugger down the alley"; "the dog chased the rabbit" [syn: chase, chase after, trail, tail, tag, give chase, go after, track] [also: dogging, dogged]  
Definition for car is: 
car 
n 1: 4-wheeled motor vehicle; usually propelled by an internal combustion engine; "he needs a car to get to work" [syn: auto, automobile, machine, motorcar] 
2: a wheeled vehicle adapted to the rails of railroad; "three cars had jumped the rails" [syn: railcar, railway car, railroad car] 
3: a conveyance for passengers or freight on a cable railway; "they took a cable car to the top of the mountain" [syn: cable car] 
4: car suspended from an airship and carrying personnel and cargo and power plant [syn: gondola] 
5: where passengers ride up and down; "the car was on the top floor" [syn: elevator car]
```